# Attempting to share cluster access results in creating new cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have deleted the config file I used when experimenting with Kubernetes on my AWS (using [this](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.html) tutorial) and replaced it with another devs config file when they set up Kubernetes on a shared AWS (using [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/sharing-clusters.md)). When I run `kubectl config view` I see the following above the users section:

```
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: <removed>
  name: aws_kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: aws_kubernetes
    user: aws_kubernetes
  name: aws_kubernetes
current-context: aws_kubernetes
```

This leads me to believe that my config should be pointing to use our shared AWS but whenever I run `cluster/kube-up.sh` it creates a new GCE cluster so I'm thinking I'm using the wrong command to spin up the cluster on AWS.

Am I using the wrong command/missing a flag/etc? Additionally I'm thinking kube-up creates a new cluster instead of recreating a previously instantiated one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing the cluster, you shouldn't need to run `kube-up.sh` (that script only needs to be run once to initially create a cluster). Once a cluster exists, you can use the standard `kubectl` [commands](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl.html) to interact with it. Try starting with `kubectl get nodes` to verify that your configuration file has valid credentials and you see the expected AWS nodes printed in the output.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. Currently experiencing: error: couldn't read version from server: Get <ip>/api: dial tcp <ip>: connection refused

Comment: That sounds like the server endpoint you are trying to connect to isn't correct. If you've run `kube-up` since getting the config from your colleague then your local config will no longer be correct.

Comment: I've since deleted my entire config file and copied theirs over again and we are both getting the same issue on our separate machines even though he created the cluster on his machine and the master ip is the one listed in the error.

Comment: If you have ssh access to the master you should be able to check the log for the apiserver (`/var/log/kube-apiserver`) to see why it is rejecting your connection attempts.